# How to create list of arrays using map?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have this array of object:

```
let arr = 
[
   { id: "1"},
   { id: "2"},
   { id: "3"}
]
```

I would create a list of arrays, so I tried:

```
arr.map(x => x.id);
```

but this will return:

```
["1", "2", "3"]
```

I want an array for each value, eg: `["1"] ["2"] ["3"]`

Comment: So return an array?

Comment: Are you after an array of small arrays then? What you show that you want isn't a single entity.

Comment: @lurker the expected result is three array, each array have a value

Comment: `.map` isn't  going to create three independent arrays `["1"] ["2"] ["3"]`. It can, however, create an array of arrays, `[["1"], ["2"], ["3"]]`. If you want them individually, you probably want to do something with `arr.forEach(...)`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want an array of each then do

```
arr.map(x=>[x.id]);
```

Comment: `arr.map( ({id}) => [id]);`, just saying :)

Comment: @Taki, absolutely.  I usually use destructuring a lot, however I find that with labmda functions the resultant mess of brackets can make it unclear.  For an SO answer in particular I'll usually avoid unless it was part of the question.

Answer (score 6):

try this

```
arr.map(x => [x.id]);
```

Comment: this works, but if I have two properties, is possible to add both?

Answer (score 3):

Note that if you want to get an array with **all** the object values, you can use [Object.values()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values). This will work for object with one `key` and for objects with multiple `keys`.

```js
let arr = 
[
   {id: "1", foo:"bar"},
   {id: "2"},
   {id: "3"}
];

console.log(arr.map(x => Object.values(x)));
```

## Other useful cases could be:

**1)** Get an array with the `keys` for each object => [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)

```js
let arr = 
[
   {id: "1", foo:"bar"},
   {id: "2"},
   {id: "3"}
];

console.log(arr.map(x => Object.keys(x)));
```

**2)** Get an array with the pairs of `[key, value]` (entries) for each object => [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
let arr = 
[
   {id: "1", foo:"bar"},
   {id: "2"},
   {id: "3"}
];

console.log(arr.map(x => Object.entries(x)));
```